# Can I install Windows 7 64-bit in a VM on a Windows 7 64-bit host?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

I'm running a Windows 7 64-bit host, with Microsoft Virtual PC 64-bit installed.

With this setup, can I install Windows 7 64-bit in a virtual machine (VHD file) as a client OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No

Microsoft Virtual PC requires you to select an architecture so it can install the correct version. However, neither support x64/64-bit guests.

I would advise you install [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) which will allow you to install a x64/64-bit guest on pretty much any modern machine.

Comment: Microsoft’s official stance with Virtual PC is that it mostly exists now to serve as a client-side compatibility layer for problematic 32-bit applications (you can run them on a 32-bit OS in a VM).  Wil is correct, VMWare Player or Workstation is the best bet for any serious virtualization.

Comment: ..and it supported to run ecomstation (os/2).

Answer (score 0):

I use Virtualbox for running 64-bit virtual machines under Windows 7.